# play audio player when local notification generate

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

Good Morning to everyone. I am making an app for alarm clock in which i have used local notification for show alarm. But now problem is that when local notification generate on fire date then a default sound play. This sound file play for 2-3 seconds but i want to repeat that sound file while user not interact with local notification. I have made R&d On this topic but i get a same question here [Question same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980714/how-can-i-repeat-my-local-notification-sound-repeated-until-i-tap-on-its-view)

Here answer is u will generate multiple local notification. But when we generate multiple then  user have interact so much notification and if user pressed close button of notification then we can not detect that event and other notification will generate while user not pressed view button of notification because we can detect by this function

> -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification;

and we can cancel all notification here. So How i repeat sound of notification without create multiple local notification? Except local notification what i will use for make alarm clock which will work after app is not running?

Thanks in advances....

Comment: You can check whether user pressed the STOP ALARM button or not(is user still sleeping or not)